# Codeigniter approach to save all posted values in bidimensional array

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, multidimensional-array

I have a multiform and I need to insert several values to 4 user,news,feed,lat (maybe 6) tables that are related by some ID this is because an **event**  needs all this information.

my form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url();?>controller/save" name="event"/>
  <label>User Name</label>

   <!--#####FOR TABLE USER#####-->
  <input type="text" name="name">   
  <input type="text" name="name">



   <!--#####FOR TABLE NEWS#####-->
  <input type="text" name="title">   
  <input type="submit" value="body"/>


  <!--#######################
       OTHER TABLE FIELDS ...
   #######################
   -->    

   <input type="submit" value="save"/>

</form>
```

Now I would like to pass a bidimensional array to event model and then depending on value insert to corresponding table

controller event.php

```
class Event extends CI_Controller {
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->helper('url');   
        $this->load->model('event_model');     
    }

    public function save()
    {

    /** Is it possible to fill this bidimensional array with for loops???? **/

     $arr_data = array(     
          array("person", $this->input->post("name")    , $this->input->post("address")),
          array("news"  , $this->input->post("title")   , $this->input->post("body"  )),
          array("feed"  , $this->input->post("id_feed") , $this->input->post("main"  )),
          array("lat"   , $this->input->post("lat1"     , $this->input->post("lat"   ))
       ); 

        $this->event_model->insert_tables($arr_data); 

    }

}
```

Now How to receive the array in model and do the insert how to declare event_model?

```
class Event_model extends CI_Model {

    function Event_model ()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
     function insert_tables($arr_data) { 

        if( "person" )
          $this->db->insert(person_tb ,


     }

}
```

Is it necessary to use implode or something, Is there a better way to do this multiple inserting?

Comment: I don't see that much sence in the beginning of this design. Are you sure you've seen through the alternatives? For instance, I think using keys would be more logical. `array('person' => array('name' => $name, 'address' => $address))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I would do something like this...

$person = array('name' => $this->input->post("name"), 'address' => $this->input->post("address"));
$news = array('title' => $this->input->post("title"), 'body' => $this->input->post("body"));
$feed = array('id' => $this->input->post("id_feed"), 'main' => $this->input->post("main"));
$lat = array('lat1' => $this->input->post("lat1"), 'lat' => $this->input->post("lat"));

if($this->person_model->insert($person)) {
    $person_id = $this->db->insert_id();
} else {
    // handle the problem of not having an id for this entity...
}

if($this->news_model->insert($news)) {
    $news_id = $this->db->insert_id();
} else {
    // handle the problem of not having an id for this entity...
}

if ($this->feed_model->insert($feed)) {
    $feed_id = $this->db->insert_id();
} else {
    // handle the problem of not having an id for this entity...
}

if($this->lat_model->insert($lat)) {
    $lat_id = $this->db->insert_id();
} else {
    // handle the problem of not having an id for this entity...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds really complicated...why not have a model for each entity and pass the right fields to the right model? Or create a library that inserts/updates each of your models?

Comment: I do have a model for each entity even their corresponding crud, the issue here is I need to insert data to a table, but this table depends on several others thats why only a form is required.